# PreferencesActivity trigger OnSharedPreferencesChange twice

Tags: android

I have a Preference Activity that implement the changed preference listener in the following way:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity  implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Log.d("TAG", "preference " + key + " changed");
    }
}
```

When I change a value of the Preferences the listener is triggered twice which I don't understand why. Accordinly to the documentation it should be triggered only when the new value is persisted.
This is my log:

```
12-17 13:31:24.434 27391-27391/xxx D/> TAG: preference ABC
12-17 13:31:24.435 27391-27391/xxx D/> TAG: preference ABC
```

And there is 1 millisecond between the two times the listener is trigged. How can I fix this? It is wrong because I change the value only once and I am receiving two calls which is not supposed to happen

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem so instead of deleting the question I'll rather answer.
The listener must be registered in a different location:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```